# bootstrap footer is not showing full page width

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying following code.
I am trying to show full page footer on my code .
But this is not working.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.#.com" style="color: #830300"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-lg"></i> Site name</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="http://www.#.com">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="About">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Contact">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Faq">FAQ</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="Login">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="SignUp">Sign Up</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3"> </div>
                <div class="col-lg-9" style="text-align: justify">
                    <div class="page-header">
                        <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #830300">Terms of Service</h1>
                    </div>
                    <p>
                        Thank you for selecting the Services offered by us.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="footer" style="background-color: #ccc;width: 100%;padding: 10px;text-align:center">
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li><a href="About">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Terms">Terms</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Privacy">Privacy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Problem is it is not working full width footer

my working demo is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xrcwrn/1hu3xtLr/).
How to resolve this

Comment: You need to change the fixed width container class from your code.it must solve your probelm.Try my solution below...thank you

Comment: If my answer was the solution You are expected for this question please verify the  answer. so that other can figureout the right solution easily.. thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class  `container` you are using for footer having width of 750px and it always keep margins from left and right . You need to use a different class say iam using `footer-container` without any width, that must solve your problem
**Try the below solution**

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.#.com" style="color: #830300"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-lg"></i> Site name</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="http://www.#.com">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Contact">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Faq">FAQ</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="Login">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="SignUp">Sign Up</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
</div><br>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3"> </div>
            <div class="col-lg-9" style="text-align: justify">
                <div class="page-header">
                    <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #830300">Terms of Service</h1>
                </div>
                <p style="text-align: center;">
                    Thank you for selecting the Services offered by us.
            </p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="footer" style="background-color: #ccc;width: 100%;padding: 10px;text-align:center">
                <ul class="list-inline">
                    <li><a href="About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Terms">Terms</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Privacy">Privacy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

You can view the result http://www.bootply.com/kGZkU3vSft

Answer (score 0):

Use the footer div to wrap the container, not the other way around: http://jsfiddle.net/1hu3xtLr/1/

```
<div id="footer" style="background-color: #ccc;width: 100%;padding: 10px;text-align:center">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <ul class="list-inline">
                <li><a href="About">About</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="Terms">Terms</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="Contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 'container' class has a width of 750px. You can use a different class instead, without the width?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the container that you have used for footer. Try changing `.container` with `.container-fluid`

Here is the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1hu3xtLr/3/)

Answer (score 0):

what about this http://jsfiddle.net/1hu3xtLr/4/ This way footer will always be at down

```
            <footer class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom"> <div class="container">
   <div class="row">     
     <div class="col-sm-4  ">
      <span class="center-to-left">       
     </span>          
   </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="vertical-align: middle;">
         <div class="text-center" >
           <a href="#" class="text-success">About</a>
             <a href="#" class="text-success">Terms</a>
             <a href="#" class="text-success">Privacy</a>
             <a href="#" class="text-success">Contact</a>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 ">        
     </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `footer` is in `container div.` You already given width for container as `750px`. So `footer` takes that width. Place your `footer` outside the `container div` and thus you can resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is Footer is Also Act as a Container,No need to Put footer inside the Container.
remove the Container  The Problem Will Solve

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a website yesterday and ran into the same issue. here is something you might want to try if you are using standard bootstrap 3.0 libraries.

```
<div class="footer">
 <div class="container">            
  <p class="text-muted footer-text">
   Your Content Here
  </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

and here are styles for the footer class

```
.footer {
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
```